# Withrouter Error using function component and typescript jsx.element' is not assignable to parameter of type routecomponentprops

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using react typescript with function component. Trying to pass props to sub component named `Input.tsx` which defined interface for props. While export with `withrouter` getting this error. Please anyone help me.

> `jsx.element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'componenttype<routecomponentprops<any, staticcontext, unknown>>'`

Input.tsx file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

interface Inputbtn {
  id: string,
  name: string,
  type: string,
  value: string,  
  onChange: (str: string) => void;
}

const Inputbtn = (props: Inputbtn) => {
  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <div>
        <input          
          id={props.id}
          name={props.name}
          type={props.type}
          value={props.value}          
          onChange={event => props.onChange(event.target.value)}
        />        
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withRouter(Inputbtn);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by extending RouteComponentProps in your Inputbtn interface like this

```
import { withRouter, RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";

interface Inputbtn extends RouteComponentProps {
  id: string,
  name: string,
  type: string,
  value: string,  
  onChange: (str: string) => void;
}
```

source: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/17355#issuecomment-711040272